# Date range and outliers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am going to try and explain this (simplified)...

I have a query that gathers data from a table using primarily a data range as the qualifier;

```
select parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
from orders
where order_dt_tm between to_date("2013-05-30 00:00:00", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date("2013-05-30 23:59:59")
```

So, the order_id is unique and the parent_order_id has many children order_id's

```
parent_order_id    order_id    order_dt_tm
---------------    --------    -----------
111.00             112.00      2013-05-29 06:00:00
111.00             113.00      2013-05-29 18:00:00
111.00             114.00      2013-05-30 06:00:00
111.00             115.00      2013-05-30 18:00:00  
111.00             116.00      2013-05-31 06:00:00
111.00             117.00      2013-05-31 18:00:00
```

My problem is that I need the results of the aforementioned query plus the highest result before my from date and the lowest after my end date. Basically I would like my result set to be;

```
parent_order_id    order_id    order_dt_tm
---------------    --------    -----------
111.00             113.00      2013-05-29 18:00:00
111.00             114.00      2013-05-30 06:00:00
111.00             115.00      2013-05-30 18:00:00  
111.00             116.00      2013-05-31 06:00:00
```

I do not know what the date range at run time or the qualifier for the outlier and I must only pass the highest and lowest.

There is a lot of data on this table and I have tried things like the following to get the previous highest value.

```
select parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
from orders
where order_dt_tm between to_date("2013-05-30 00:00:00", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date("2013-05-30 23:59:59")
    or order_id = 
             (select distinct FIRST_VALUE(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_order_id ORDER BY order_id DESC
             from orders
             where order_dt_tm < to_date("2013-05-30 00:00:00", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
             )
```

The problem is; it is SLOW...the parent query in a table of 5M+ rows with all its other quals is fast. The order_dt_tm is part of an index. But whatever way I apply the qualification to get the outliers it becomes horrifically slow.

Additionally, I am not sure I can always be sure that the order_id is the highest value for the date. Really it should be achieved by date and time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you use 3 queries 1 to get max , 1 to list and 1 to get min and connect them all using UNION, this will remove the duplicates or UNION ALL if you want the Duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient query would probably be something like this:

```
-- last row of previous day
SELECT parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
  FROM (SELECT parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
          FROM orders
         WHERE order_dt_tm < :date_start
         ORDER BY order_dt_tm DESC)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
UNION ALL
<your_query>
UNION ALL
-- first row of the next day
SELECT parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
  FROM (SELECT parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
          FROM orders
         WHERE order_dt_tm > :date_end
         ORDER BY order_dt_tm)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

I think a single regular index on `order_dt_tm` can be used for the first and the last subquery to perform a very efficient one-row range scan.

Comment: This is a really good approach...thanks Vincent. Much faster!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [lag and lead](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php)

```
select parent_order_id, order_id, order_dt_tm
from
(
    select parent_order_id
    ,      order_id
    ,      order_dt_tm
    ,      lag(order_dt_tm) over (order by order_dt_tm)  prev_order_dt_tm
    ,      lead(order_dt_tm) over (order by order_dt_tm) next_order_dt_tm
    from   orders
)
where  next_order_dt_tm >= to_date('2013-05-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  -- start_date of range
and    prev_order_dt_tm <= to_date('2013-05-30 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  -- end_date of range
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need the data from the row immediately preceding and succeeding the date range to be at the same level, this would move that data to a set of columns at the same level.

Comment: That's why we select order_dt_tm, not the prev_ or next_ columns. Try it. :)